# Nuxt JS Resources not found in IIS Server

Tags: nuxtjs3

I uploaded my Nuxt app in IIS Server by copying the public folder (generated by npm run generate),
and from the server,  I have a folder inside of the directory, so my url would be apps.mywebsite/nuxtapp/, when I trying to open my nuxt app in the browser, it return error that my resources was not found, can someone help me about this, thank you in advance.

I have tried to modify my nuxt.config.js to configure the route path and the base folder, but still not working.